# Splitting data set in to windows and getting min value from that window in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I'm having trouble splitting a data set into several other data sets so I can get the min values out of them. Base line for this: Key can be used simultaneously in different countries (country id's are in column **a**). One key(column **b** in picture) can be reused again after a certain period of time, in this case 120 days. One key can have about 10 events for it along with dates.

[Picture with sample data (I have colored the theoretical boundaries for each of the periods or whatever you call them)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxxQg.png)

The thing I tried doing is, taking the first date of the whole set and partitioning over **a** and **b** columns and using `datediff()` to get the number of days between the min date of the whole set and each separate event. and then afterwards using the number that was returned by datediff/120 to group them. The thing I really wanted to do is take the min date of each set(not the whole set) and calculate based on that. I really hope I explained clearly enough for you kind helpers to understand what I'm after. Now that I think of.. I'm kindoff worried that even if I did get the min date of a single set and then divide it by 120, I would get incorrect results. Any suggestions appreciated!

I Used something like this: `DATEDIFF(d,min(dates) OVER (PARTITION BY a, b), dates)/120`

[Visual explanation of what I need to achieve and how.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74jrn.png)

```
                sample data                                   desired outcome
|  CountryId  |    Key      |     date     |    |  CountryId  |      Key    |     date     | 
|-------------|-------------|--------------|    |-------------|-------------|--------------|
|  2          |  093123124  |  2015-04-16  |    |  2          |  093123124  |  2015-04-16  |
|  2          |  093123124  |  2015-04-16  |    |  2          |  093123124  |  2015-11-24  |
|  2          |  093123124  |  2015-04-17  |    |  2          |  093123124  |  2016-04-17  |
|  2          |  093123124  |  2015-04-17  |
|  2          |  093123124  |  2015-11-24  |
|  2          |  093123124  |  2015-11-24  |
|  2          |  093123124  |  2015-11-25  |
|  2          |  093123124  |  2015-11-25  |
|  2          |  093123124  |  2015-11-25  |
|  2          |  093123124  |  2016-04-17  |
|  2          |  093123124  |  2016-04-18  |
|  2          |  093123124  |  2016-04-20  |
|  2          |  093123124  |  2016-04-21  |
|  2          |  093123124  |  2016-04-22  |
```

Comment: Is bettter if you post your data as text, we cant copy paste from picture. Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Added data as text so it is easier to copy, as well as expected outcome. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: At first looks like a `DISTINCT` ... But I dont understant the logic for your desire output. where go `11-25` ? Also instead of using `a, b, c`  use meaninful variable names

Comment: You need explain your logic. What is a set? show us examples.

Comment: I created a visual representation of what i need to achieve. Example is included. This is as detailed as it gets. http://i.stack.imgur.com/74jrn.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem like a case for [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). The following code find each set recursively adding 120 days for each recursion.

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD
DECLARE @SampleData TABLE(  A   INT,
                            B   NVARCHAR(25),
                            C   DATETIME)


INSERT INTO @SampleData(A, B, C)
VALUES (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-04-16')),
       (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-04-16')),
       (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-04-17')),
       (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-04-17')),
       (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-11-24')),
       (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-11-24')),
       (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-11-25')),
       (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-11-25')),
       (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-11-25')),
       (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-04-17')),
       (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-04-18')),
       (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-04-20')),
       (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-04-21')),
      -- (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-03-24')),
       (2,'093123124', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-04-22'));

WITH lvl1
AS
(
    SELECT  A, 
            B, 
            C = MIN(C)
    FROM @SampleData
    GROUP BY    A,
                B
),
lvlOthers
AS
(
    SELECT  A,
            B,
            C
    FROM lvl1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  S.A,
            S.B,
            C = MIN(S.C) OVER(PARTITION BY S.A, S.B)
    FROM lvlOthers
    INNER JOIN @SampleData AS S ON  lvlOthers.A = S.A
                                AND lvlOthers.B = S.B
                                AND S.C > DATEADD(DAY, 120, lvlOthers.C)
)

SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C
FROM lvlOthers
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100)
```

Beaware that this code isn't fine tuned for performance. In fact, it will perform badly on large dataset.

Also, the maxrecursion should be increased if the range of dates exceed ~32 years.

Comment: Awesome! This is just what I needed to get on the right track.